How to Optimize Spring Boot Native Image Compilation in GitHub Actions?
I'm trying to compile a small Spring Boot application to a native image using GitHub Actions, but the process is taking an extremely long time—over 20 minutes, which makes it almost unusable. The application itself is quite small, so I don't understand why the compilation time is so long.
Here's an outline of my current GitHub Actions workflow:
name: Native Image Compile and Deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      app:
        description: 'Choose the application to build and deploy'
        required: true
        default: 'app-one'
        options:
          - app-one
          - app-two

jobs:
  native-image-compile:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Cache Gradle dependencies to speed up build times
      - name: Cache Gradle Dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
            build/
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*', '**/gradle-wrapper.properties', '**/native-image.properties') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gradle

      # Setup GraalVM using the GitHub Action for GraalVM
      - uses: graalvm/setup-graalvm@v1
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'graalvm'
          components: 'native-image'

      # Compile the application to a native image
      - name: Compile Application to Native Image
        run: |
          APP_NAME=${{ github.event.inputs.app }}
          
          # Use Gradle Daemon and configure Gradle to be faster
          ./gradlew --no-daemon :applications:$APP_NAME:nativeCompile --parallel --max-workers=2

      # Build and tag the Docker image
      - name: Build and Tag Docker Image
        run: |
          APP_NAME=${{ github.event.inputs.app }}
          BRANCH_NAME=${{ github.ref_name }}
          
          docker build -t $APP_NAME:$BRANCH_NAME .
          docker save $APP_NAME:$BRANCH_NAME -o $APP_NAME-$BRANCH_NAME.tar

      # Tag the GitHub Branch with a Timestamp
      - name: Tag the GitHub Branch
        env:
          APP_NAME: ${{ github.event.inputs.app }}
          BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.ref_name }}
        run: |
          TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
          TAG_NAME="$BRANCH_NAME-$APP_NAME-$TIMESTAMP"
          git tag $TAG_NAME
          git push origin $TAG_NAME

I've already tried caching Gradle dependencies and enabling parallel compilation, but it hasn't made a significant difference.
My questions are:

Are there any specific strategies or configurations I can apply to reduce the native image compilation time?
Are there alternative approaches for optimizing the GitHub Actions workflow for compiling Spring Boot applications to native images?
Is there a known limitation or issue with GraalVM or GitHub Actions that could be causing these long compilation times?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Without knowing which part takes the most time it will be impossible to answer. Given that know that Github Actions (especially the free one) is limited in the resources it gives you and native compilation will take time.

@M.Deinum seems like spring boot native is almost useless, if you need fast deployment. Hoped that there was some easy tweaks.

Why is it useless for fast deployment? To be able to deploy fast everything needs to be calculated/compiled that takes time. That has nothing to do with Spring Boot but the fact that you opted for Native as Native compilation will take time, considerably more then regular compilation (which is also stated in the documentation).

Try this change to your workflow that improves gradle caching. See more information on setting up gradle here
jobs:
  native-image-compile:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - uses: graalvm/setup-graalvm@v1
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'graalvm'
          components: 'native-image'

      - name: Setup Gradle and Gradle caching
        uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@v4

      - name: Compile Application to Native Image
        run: |
          APP_NAME=${{ inputs.app }}
          ./gradlew --no-daemon :applications:$APP_NAME:nativeCompile --parallel --max-workers=2


Thank you for your suggestion, didn't make any differ :(
Went from 28 minutes to 30 minutes compile time.
But the suggested code is cleaner :)

This does not sound right. Is this on the second run?

Yes, but after changing to bootBuildImage it went to half time :/
